# How to restore/view DVD UDF burned session

Tags: windows-explorer, dvd-burning

I have to recover 1.8GB of pictures from a multisession DVD (Session 2from4).

Now when I try to continue a multisession disc Nero says that this file format is not compliant with ISO9660 Joliet, and aborts it calling the disc corrupt.

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and I cannot see any of these UDF sessions in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a UDF is one thing, reading it on Winodws is another, see if tis helps.

http://forums.techarena.in/windows-software/1126559.htm

In the future use another format besides UDF, its so incompatible with windows,
.